# Testing in erlang

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, erlang, erlang-shell

I was trying to learn testing in Erlang. I used the code base of a tic-tac-toe game present at this [link](https://github.com/bekkopen/erlang-tictactoe/tree/master/src). It is a two player game(let's call it a pair of players).I basically wanted to check that what happens when multiple pairs play this game simultaneously.
So I tried writing a basic and a simple module to test it called `testing` which is as follows:

```
-module(testing).

%% ====================================================================
%% API functions
%% ====================================================================
-export([all/0]).



%% ====================================================================
%% Internal functions
%% ====================================================================
all()->

    test1(),
    timer:sleep(75),
    test2(),
    timer:sleep(75),
    test3(),
    timer:sleep(75).





test1()->

    G_serv_Output1=gameserver:start(),
    io:format("Value of G_serv_Output in test1 is ~p~n",
              [G_serv_Output1]),
    Abhishek=gameclient:login("Abhishek"),
    Dharun=gameclient:login("Dharun"),


    gameclient:new_game(Abhishek,"Dharun"),

    timer:sleep(5),

    gameclient:make_move(Abhishek,"Dharun", a1),
    timer:sleep(5),
    gameclient:make_move(Dharun,"Abhishek", b2),
    timer:sleep(5),
    gameclient:make_move(Abhishek,"Dharun", a2),
    timer:sleep(5), 
    gameclient:make_move(Dharun,"Abhishek", c3),
    timer:sleep(5),
    gameclient:make_move(Abhishek,"Dharun", a3).




test2()->

    G_serv_Output1=gameserver:start(),
    io:format("Value of G_serv_Output in test2 is ~p~n",
               [G_serv_Output1]),
    Abhijeet=gameclient:login("Abhijeet"),
    Ranjan=gameclient:login("Ranjan"),


    gameclient:new_game(Abhijeet,"Ranjan"),
    timer:sleep(5),

    gameclient:make_move(Abhijeet,"Ranjan", a1),
    timer:sleep(5),
    gameclient:make_move(Ranjan,"Abhijeet", b2),
    timer:sleep(5),
    gameclient:make_move(Abhijeet,"Ranjan", a2),
    timer:sleep(5), 
    gameclient:make_move(Ranjan,"Abhijeet", c3),
    timer:sleep(5),
    gameclient:make_move(Abhijeet,"Ranjan", a3).





test3()->

    G_serv_Output1=gameserver:start(),
    io:format("Value of G_serv_Output in test3 is ~p~n",
              [G_serv_Output1]),
    Bana=gameclient:login("Bana"),
    Sagar=gameclient:login("Sagar"),


    gameclient:new_game(Bana,"Sagar"),
    timer:sleep(5),

    gameclient:make_move(Bana,"Sagar", a1),
    timer:sleep(5),
    gameclient:make_move(Sagar,"Bana", b2),
    timer:sleep(5),
    gameclient:make_move(Bana,"Sagar", a2),
    timer:sleep(5), 
    gameclient:make_move(Sagar,"Bana", c3),
    timer:sleep(5),
    gameclient:make_move(Bana,"Sagar", a3).
```

All the three tests ran fine and I saw all the three games completing.

Then I noticed that the functions like `gameclient:new_game/2` and  `gameclient:new_game/3` were also taking in `Opponent name` as input, which I decided to remove so I changed `new_game/2 to new_game/1` and `make_move/3 to make_move/2` in `gameclient` as follows:

```
new_game(Pid) ->
    Pid ! {new_game}.

make_move(Pid, Move) -> 

    Pid ! { make_move, Move }.
loop(Name) ->
    receive
        { new_game} ->
            gameserver:new_game(Name),
            loop(Name);
        { make_move, Move } ->
            gameserver:make_move(Name, Move),
            loop(Name)

    end.
```

and in `gameserver` module as:

```
new_game(Name) ->
    global:send(?SERVER, { new_game, Name}).

make_move(Name, Move) ->
    global:send(?SERVER, { make_move, Name, Move }).

game_loop(Players, Games) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    receive
        { new_game, Name} ->
            PlayerList=dict:fetch_keys(Players),
            PlayerAndOpponent=lists:partition(fun(A)->Name==A end, PlayerList),
            {_,OpponentNameList}=PlayerAndOpponent,
            OpponentName=list_to_tuple(OpponentNameList),
            case dict:find(Name, Players) of
                { ok, Pid } ->
                    case dict:find(element(1,OpponentName), Players) of
                        { ok, OpponentPid} ->
                            Pid ! { msg, "Ready to rumble against " ++ element(1,OpponentName) ++ "!" },
                            OpponentPid ! { msg, "Ready to rumble against " ++ Name ++ "!" },

                            GamePid = tictactoe:start({Pid, Name}, {OpponentPid, element(1,OpponentName)}),

                            GameKey = create_game_key(Name, element(1,OpponentName)),


                            link(GamePid),
                            game_loop(Players, dict:store(GameKey, GamePid, Games));
                        error ->
                            Pid ! { msg, "Did not find opponent " ++ OpponentName ++ "!" },
                            game_loop(Players, Games)
                    end;
                error ->
                    io:format("Could not find player ~p~n", [ Name ]),
                    game_loop(Players, Games)
            end;


        { make_move, Name, Move } ->
            PlayerList=dict:fetch_keys(Players),
            PlayerAndOpponent=lists:partition(fun(A)->Name==A end, PlayerList),
            {_,OpponentNameList}=PlayerAndOpponent,
            OpponentName=list_to_tuple(OpponentNameList),

            case dict:find(create_game_key(Name, element(1,OpponentName)), Games) of
                { ok, GamePid } ->

                    tictactoe:make_move(GamePid, Name, Move),
                    game_loop(Players, Games);
                error ->
                    game_loop(Players, Games)
            end

    end.
```

*leaving rest of the code in both the modules unchanged.*

But Now when I ran the module I found that only test1 ran successfully and test2 and test3 didn't. **I tried finding the reason for this and I found that when test2 and test3 start the names of the player from test1 was still in the dict, but since I have called `gameserver:start/0`** in all the three tests this shouldn't be happening.

Questions:

If I have to test this tictactoe game for two users but they must be playing concurrently then how should my test case module be like?

**After EDIT**
I looked into erlang's common_test library and implemented it on my same problem
by creating a new module `testing2` as follows:

```
-module(testing2).
-include_lib("common_test/include/ct.hrl").
%% ====================================================================
%% API functions
%% ====================================================================
-export([all/0, groups/0, init_per_group/2, end_per_group/2]).
-export([test1/1,test2/1]).



%% ====================================================================
%% Internal functions
%% ====================================================================
all() -> [{group, session}].

groups() -> [{session,
              [],
              [{group, clients}]},
             {clients,
              [parallel, {repeat, 1}],
              [test1, test2]}].

init_per_group(session, Config) ->
   gameserver:start(),
    Config;
init_per_group(_, Config) ->
    Config.

end_per_group(session, _Config) ->
    gameserver:stop();
end_per_group(_, _Config) ->
    ok.

test1(_Config)->



Abhishek=gameclient:login("Abhishek"),
Dharun=gameclient:login("Dharun"),


gameclient:new_game(Abhishek),

    timer:sleep(10),

    gameclient:make_move(Abhishek, a1),
    timer:sleep(10),
    gameclient:make_move(Dharun, b2),
    timer:sleep(10),
    gameclient:make_move(Abhishek, a2),
    timer:sleep(10),    
    gameclient:make_move(Dharun, c3),
    timer:sleep(10),
    gameclient:make_move(Abhishek, a3).





test2(_Config)->



Abhijeet=gameclient:login("Abhijeet"),
Ranjan=gameclient:login("Ranjan"),


gameclient:new_game(Abhijeet),
    timer:sleep(10),

    gameclient:make_move(Abhijeet, a1),
    timer:sleep(10),
    gameclient:make_move(Ranjan, b2),
    timer:sleep(10),
    gameclient:make_move(Abhijeet, a2),
    timer:sleep(10),    
    gameclient:make_move(Ranjan, c3),
    timer:sleep(10),
    gameclient:make_move(Abhijeet, a3).
```

But when I see in the html logs generated by ct I still cannot see these games running but instead I see the following 
**In test1**

```
=== Started at 2017-09-19 11:48:08



"Welcome to tictactoe server!"

"Welcome to tictactoe server!"

"Ready to rumble against Abhishek!"

"Ready to rumble against Dharun!"




=== Ended at 2017-09-19 11:48:08
=== successfully completed test case
=== Returned value: {make_move,a3}
```

**and in test2**

```
=== Started at 2017-09-19 11:48:08



"Welcome to tictactoe server!"

"Welcome to tictactoe server!"

"Ready to rumble against Ranjan!"

"Ready to rumble against Abhijeet!"

"It is not your turn yet!"

"It is not your turn yet!"




=== Ended at 2017-09-19 11:48:08
=== successfully completed test case
=== Returned value: {make_move,a3}
```

Please help me out here.

Comment: My take on testing is pretty strict. You can test pure functions meaningfully and externally test integrated systems meaningfully, but in between is a bunch of fuzzy insanity nobody ever seems to handle better than user testing achieves in the real world (though many religions and ideologies have sprung up around this). That said, I believe that the *absolute best* use of your time would be to learn about [Dialyzer](http://erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html) first, and then property based testing [PropER](http://proper.softlab.ntua.gr/). Other testing methodologies and frameworks can wait.

Comment: @zxq9 thank you for the links.So does that mean that how the project(this game) would behave when multiple users will be playing it can only be checked when actually multiple pairs of people are playing this in the real world.can't we check it by writing a single module or two?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not that simple with concurrency. Everything you write between processes has at best a partial event ordering. System states are therefore unprovable. Erlang's "let it crash" and strict process isolation was designed as a *reaction to the difficulty of managing this*. Concurrent systems are fantastically subtle and complex, so when we hit unexpected cases we crash. Your testing models will only be as reliable as your analysis (you'll miss something). If you thought of it for testing, *you would have already written the module to handle it*. The exception is pure functions.

Comment: Actually I am new to erlang and my goal is to understand how testing happens in erlang. So if I have some project written in erlang,1) should I only check it unit wise only. 2)And how can I actually test that project for concurrency then?

Comment: @abhishekranjan It is great that you provided a link to your code, but it would be even better if you had there branch with changes described in the question.  It would make much easier to find what is not working in your code.

Comment: @mpm actually my concern is that I want to write a test module such that it can start and run multiple games concurrently and not one after another(i.e. multiple games running side by side). And with that purpose in my I realize that even my first attempt was wrong as I was calling test1/0, test2/0 etc separated by timer:sleep /1 which runs game one after another, but it is not something that I wanted. So basically I have figured out the problem but I still don't know how to proceed in order to write a test module that runs concurrent games. Can anyone help me out here with some suggestions

Comment: Either `[spawn(?MODULE, T, []) || T <- [test1, test2, test3]]` (you could use `spawn_link`), or use `parallel` option for group when using Common Test (like described [here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/common-test-for-uncommon-tests#test-groups)). If you are learning [this](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/eunit) and [this](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/common-test-for-uncommon-tests) chapter should be enough.

Comment: @mpm thank you for the links. I will try to learn and play with it

Comment: I have used ct in erlang and I have edited my question above. what I expected was that there would be a different instance of 'gameserver','gameclient' ,'serv_utils' and 'tictatoe.erl' respectively for 'test1' and 'test2' and the data generated by 'test1' would have nothing to do with 'test2'. But I feel that both test1 and test2 are working on the same copy of the files mentioned above. Is there any problem in the way this game is designed, I mean by using dicts or registering ?SERVER name as server which is creating a hinderance  in the parallel execution of test1 and test2 respectively?

Comment: You should think about splitting up your question. We started with one thing, moved to another, and now we are discussing third.  This is not a good practice on StackOverflow, and it only makes harder for you to get an answer. And just going on in comments is not the way. I would recommend [1] consider if **"Testing in Erlang"** is really a question with an answer [2] Think if this entry will help anyone else in future, and maybe remove delete your question [3]  Try to as new, specific question regarding your current problem.

Comment: `But I feel that both test1 and test2 are working on the same copy of the files mentioned above.` is something some might give you more insight on. I would really encourage you to try again, I'm sure you will not be disappointed.

Comment: @mpm I have to agree here with you that it is looking like we are dicussing separate problems but I was always clear that I want to test for concurrent players playing this tic-tac-toe game at a single time. But I have to admit that my initial tries were way too here and there and I wasn't able to use correct words to define the problem. Also I do very much care that it might help people in future and this was the reason I didn't delete my previous question but rather edited it. But still my question remains the same about concurrency

Comment: @mpm no no I am not at all dissapointed, rather through this question I got exposure to ct and eunit in erlang, and I am very happy about it.And yes I am trying again.I have in mind that I should replace dict with mnesia,and see how it goes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154798/discussion-between-mpm-and-abhishek-ranjan).